# PHP pages keep loading

Tags: php, timeout

I am sure this has to do with the fact that I just uninstalled PHP and reinstalled a newer version (Ubuntu). I am having an issue where the page loads, but continues loading until it times out. A simple 'Hello World' page would return the 'Hello World' text, but the page would keep loading until timeout. This happens on just about any page that is not served statically, and eventually causes other errors in javascript. I have noticed that this happens even if I place a die() at the end or beginning of the script? Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked php.ini configuration? maybe something will catch your eye

Comment: Analyse Developer Tools Network panel during the request. That might give some hints.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know a little more information. What PHP version did you have? What version did you upgrade to? Do you notice any differences between the old INI file and the new one? Did you update Apache at the same time?